# Macro that loops through class members and generates code

Tags: class, visual-c++

.h

```
class CCvars
{
public:
    bool gui;
    int size;
    float precision;
}
extern CCvars g_Cvars;
```

what I want to do is

```
#define CVAR_WRITE(cv) \
    std::string str(#cv); \
    ...

#define SAVE_CVARS(cvarObject) \
    // Loop through every class member in cvarObject and do \
    CVAR_WRITE(classMember);
```

and now in my main function I will just do

```
void SaveCvars()
{
    CCvars g_Cvars;

    SAVE_CVARS(g_Cvars);
}
```

and this should be equal to

```
void SaveCvars()
{
    CCvars g_Cvars;

    // so it will generate this for me

    // for simplicity but you get the idea
    CVAR_WRITE(g_Cvars.gui);
    CVAR_WRITE(g_Cvars.size);
    CVAR_WRITE(g_Cvars.precision);
}
```

Is there way to do it without putting every class member into vector array ?

Comment: C++ doesn't, at this time, support reflection. The approach I like for this kind of task is to write a script in your scripting language of choice that takes a simple description of the data, and generates the necessary boilerplate C++ code.

Comment: this just does its job before compiling